# Decimal negative and positive numbers sum

Tags: java, c#

In Java and C#:

```
int a = (int)(-1.5 + 2.5);
int b = (int)(-1.55 + 2.55);
int c = (int)(1.45 + 2.55);
// a = 1; b = 0; c = 4;
```

Could anyone explain why adding positive number to negative one with 2 or more digits after decimal point causes decimal number break? "b = 0.99999999999999978".

So the question is - why "-1.5 + 2.5 = 1", but "-1.55 + 2.55 = 0"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because type `double` is an approximation.

Usually `double` denotes to [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standart type [decimal64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format)

---

> `Math.Round` allows you to specify a **MidpointRounding**:
>
> **ToEven** - When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest even number.
>
> **AwayFromZero** - When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest number that is away from zero.

Example:

```
var val = (int)Math.Round((-1.55 + 2.55), 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Output : 1

---

Common bug for beginners is to write code like :

```
for (double i = 0.0; i == 6.0; i+=0.1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Hint: This will will not end in ~60 steps.

Comment: Also 0.99999999999999978 does not round to closest integer when you cast to int, but takes the Floor - it will become 0.

Comment: That's clear, but -1.5 is a double as well. Why it affects the only double numbers with 2+ digits after the point?

Comment: @Maksim: That has nothing to do with the number of decimal digits. If you try `int d = (int)(-1.54 + 2.54)` the result will be again the expected one. As Johan Prins said in his answer: some decimals can't be represented exactly as floating point number.

Comment: Ok, so it's really important to check doubles before using them as integers and either use round function or BigDecimals. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some decimals in the IEEE-754 format cannot be represented correctly when using double. Rather use BigDecimal.
For example:

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("-1.55").add(new BigDecimal("2.55"));
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid converting double to String?

Comment: It is recommended to use the String constructor on BigDecimal as the double constructor can also give incorrect results. Based on that I am going to go with "no". Try not to use double for these calculations in the first place.